# Two Click actions on mobile screen

Tags: interface, accessibility, human-interface-guideline

I was working on a mobile project and I faced a problem.
How do I show if there are two different actions on a single object in mobile?

[image]

In this screen all options have sub-options that appear on a new page that slides in after clicking on **Option 1 from Level 1**. How do I take the user back to **Option 1 page** from the Sub Option page? Which action should trigger this?

[image]

Comment: If I understand this correctly, we are looking at some sort of navigational menu that runs (at least) two levels deep and you want users to be able to navigate the menu AND be able to go directly to pages from both levels. - I'm not sure that's possible without over complicating the menu.

Comment: I put some generic solutions to your problem in my answer. If you can provide any more detail or context about what an "option" might be, I can focus my answer better.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to give the ability to use the parent and child links of a menu option. Here are some ideas:

**1. Include the Option link in the Sub-Option Link**

Simply include the Option 1 link in the Sub-Options list to allow the user to go to that page.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIXXan.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**2. Expand Menus**

If you want to keep all options on one level, expand the menu to show the sub-options. This can be done using an arrow or accordion. All options are clickable.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDUU0R.png)</sup>

Comment: But in my design all options under level 1 has sub options and both the options in level 1 has a page dedicated to it so design should accompany two actions one is to ope sub options and other is to open option 1 page

Comment: I understand a bit more now. Making some edits.